# Omni light in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I want to basically create a light that will make it so that its very bright around the player then gets progressively darker. Sort of like a fire torch. How can I get this effect? I can only seem to get an ambient light? How can it follow the camera?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using GLSL or the fixed function pipeline?

Comment: As the camera is moved, so should you move the light source. Am I missing the obvious? Many OpenGL implementations have a hardware limit on the number of light sources that can be rendered but it doesn't sound like you are hitting that limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you are looking for is known as a point light.

If you are using fixed function, the following tutorial may be use to you:
http://jerome.jouvie.free.fr/OpenGl/Tutorials/Tutorial13.php

Just note that this tutorial appears to use jogl with Java, but the conversion to C++ should be relatively straightforward.

For a glsl implementation, Lighthouse3d has a tutorial for GLSL 1.2 implementation of point lights.